# 正規表現 "該当文字の前の行に文字が含まれていない" を表現したい

Tags: 正規表現

正規表現で以下のような条件を検索したいです。

条件：bodyの前行にsetClassが含まれていないこと

×

```
xxx.setClass()
var body
```

⚪︎

```
xxx.reload()
var body
```

正規表現に詳しい方、ご教授いただけますと幸いです。

##### 追記

チェックはこのサイトを使用して行なっています。
https://weblabo.oscasierra.net/tools/regex/

試した正規表現：

1行前は正常に取れているようだが、含まれていないの部分がうまく機能してくれない。

```
(([^\n]*\n){0,1}.*?body)(?!.*setClass)
```

Comment: 正規表現を使う場所(テキストエディタやプログラム言語)をご教示ください。また、既に試してうまく行かなかった正規表現があれば質問に追記をお願いします。

Comment: 正規表現を使う場所はSwiftLintのカスタムルールになります。別途質問に試した正規表現を追記します。

Comment: `(?<!setClass.*?\n.*?)var body`

Comment: 上記の正規表現で無事に検索できました。大変助かりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 解決した場合にはぜひコメント欄でのやり取りで終わらせず、自己回答の形で投稿してみてください。